# How to show another layout in listactivity

Tags: android, listview, layout, listactivity

I have a listactivity which contains a listview. i want to show another layout which contains a button at top and a webview at bottom on this listview and that layout always to be shown. I tried this but this is not what i want to do :

```
ListView lv =getListView();
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayer, lv, false);
lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

This shows my layout but when i scroll my listview, needless to say that when i scroll my listview down it is no more to be shown like it is part of my other listview items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `ListActivity`, you can use any layout you want. The only contract you must follow is putting a `ListView` whose id is `list`. Thus, you can do something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/something"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="What ever"/>
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/something"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you do want to reuse another layout, change the `TextView` for something like `<include>` (take a look at [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html)).