# ListActivity using an overall layout to provide a non-scrolling heading

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to do what should be very simple: have a LinearLayout containing a TextView and a ListView.

In one of the [CommonsWare books](http://commonsware.com/) is an example that as far as I can see is effectively the same as my example.  However, mine fails (stopped unexpectedly; received a RuntimeException) if the setContentView call in onCreate is called.  Commenting it out makes the list display fine, but I have no heading.

According to [How to show another layout in listactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876128/how-to-show-another-layout-in-listactivity) I have to make sure my ListView has an id of "list".  Mine does.

What am I missing?  Here is main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:text="Constant Heading" android:id="@+id/heading"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ListView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

listitem.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
```

and here is the code that uses it:

```
package com.explorenm.usstates;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class USStates extends ListActivity {
    static final String[] STATES = new String[] {
            "Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California",
            "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida",
            "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana",
            "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine",
            "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota",
            "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska",
            "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico",
            "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio",
            "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island",
            "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas",
            "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West
            Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Connect the array to the list view
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem, STATES));

        //Allow the user to jump to an entry by typing
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        // Provide code to execute if the list item is clicked.
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the text in the list item
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  375): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.explorenm.usstates/com.explorenm.usstates.USStates}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:210)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at com.explorenm.usstates.USStates.onCreate(USStates.java:31)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
E/AndroidRuntime(  375):        ... 11 more
```

I note that it says "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'".  As far as I can see, I do (android:id="@+id/list" in main.xml); see the complete file above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Aha. I found it. I had

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

when it needed to be

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` on both the `TextView` and `ListView`, and set `android:layout_weight="1"` on the `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:text="Constant Heading" android:id="@+id/heading"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will cause the `ListView` to expand to fill the available area.

Comment: Doesn't work on 2.3.1 or 2.1 (both in the emulator).  If it helps any, the problem is occurring in ListACtivity.onContentChanged() at line 236.  I tried both this answer as well as the answer below and both resulted in the same.

Comment: You need to provide the full stacktrace of the error, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` on the TextView. Set `android:layout_weight="1"` `android:layout_height="0dp"` on the ListView:

Comment: See my comment above for more details; short answer, this does not work on 2.1 or 2.3.1.